# Avoid .xml files when using costura.fody

Tags: c#, fody-costura

I would like to get a Single .EXE File so I'm using `Costura.Fody`.

After adding its NuGet package all of the DLLs are embeded to the .EXE file as expected.
The problem is that I get all of those .xml files:

[image]

PS1: I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1 (not able to use newer releases becouse of some of the DLLs).

PS2: Are those files required? Maybe I can delete them straight away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default and sometimes frustrating behavior of `costura.fody`.
If you notice, all of the following assemblies have their build option:

- Generate Xml Documentation set to true

`costura.fody` takes those dlls and generates xml documentations that are oversizing your folder.

The solution is to exclude those files, look it up at the `costura.fody` github channel.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is a little bit older,
my solution is to add in the build event a post-build command

```
del "$(TargetDir)*.xml"
```

I hope this help someone with the same problem